# Reading from a data file to 2D array. No output. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to programming and c++. I am working on an assignment which requires me to read data from a data file and store it into a 2D array. Every line in the text file is in the following format(data type is int)

XXXX XX XX XX XX ...(and so on)

The four digit number is actually student ID and is to be stored in a separate 1D array. I have done this part and I don't have any issues. Now the rest 2 digit numbers are to be stored in a 2D array with 4 columns and X rows, where X is the number of lines in the data file.

I have written the following code to try to read into the file. It gives no error and compiles correctly but when I try to print the 2D array, using `cout`, I don't get anything. Nothing. Please look at the following code and try to help me.

I am new to stackoverflow and programming so please forgive me if the code is not formatted correctly or is not as per the tradition.

```
//___CODE____
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

//Global
const int SIZE = 1000;
int const col = 4; 
string fileName; 


//Function Prototypes
int readId(int id[], int size);
int readScores(int scores[][col], int size);

//Main
int main()
{
int examScores[SIZE][col];
int id[SIZE] = {}; 

cout<<endl; 

readId(id, SIZE);                                
readScores(examScores, SIZE);                   



}
//Declarations

int readId(int id[], int size)
{
ifstream inputFile;
int count = 0;
int total = 0; //Size of id [] OR no. of students.
int temp = 0;

//Takes the name of the data file from the user.
//NOTE: The filename should include its extension.
cout<<"Enter the name of the data file (including the extension):";
cin>>fileName;

inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
        while(inputFile >> temp)
        {
            if(count % 5 == 0)
            {
                id[total] = temp;
                total++;
            }
            ++count;
        }
    }

else
    cout<<"Data file not found!"<<endl; // If this is executed make sure the data file
                                        //is located in the same directory as this program.
//To print the content of array. Check.
for(int i=0; i < total; i++)
    cout<<id[i]<<endl;

return total;
}


int readScores(int scores[][col], int size)
{
ifstream inputFile;

int count = 0;
int c = 0; //Counter for column.
int total = 0; //No. of students.
int temp = 0;

inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
        while(inputFile >> temp)
        {
            if(count % 5 != 0)
            {
                if (c < col)
                {
                    scores[total][c] = temp;
                }
                else
                    total++;
                    c = 0;
                    scores[total][c] = temp;
            }
            ++count;
            c++;
        }
    }

else
    cout<<"Data file not found!"<<endl; // If this is executed make sure the data file
                                        //is located in the same directory as this program.

//To print the contents of 2D array. Check.
for (int r = 0; r < total; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            cout<<setw(8)<<scores[r][col];
        }
    cout<<endl;
}
return total;
}
```

Comment: Now may be a good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line to see what may be wrong.

Comment: By the way, in the `readScores` function you might want to look at the `else` statement. The indentation doesn't match the actual code, you might be missing a pair of curly parentheses (`{}`)?

Comment: The logic in the readScores function is just wrong. There's also a misunderstanding of how files work. It's pretty clear that you are expecting that when you open the file for a second time that you will already be past the student id that you read in the first function. But that's not true, each time you open the file you are back at the beginning.

Comment: what does the text file look like?

Comment: I should have made the format of the data file clear. Sorry.

Comment: xxxx xx xx xx xx <--- The data file contains lines like this. The number of lines can vary. I understand that every time data would be read from the beginning

Comment: Joachim, Thank you! The else statement was missing the '{}'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else-Statement is wrong, there are some brackets missing (now you always reset c to zero)

Comment: Thank you for your time everyone. I apologize if I was not able to make the question clear.